# What needs to be done, when publishing Open Source Software which uses other free libraries?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I would like to publish my application, which is AGPL. It can be downloaded from my website. But the archive also contains other libraries with different licenses:

- XStream (BSD)
- GWT (Apache2)
- gwt-dnd (Apache2)
- gwt-upload (Apache2)
- Commons Fileupload (Apache2)
- JDOM (Apache-style)
- iText (AGPL)
- JFreeChart (LGPL)
- JavaMail (JavaMail)

I didn't change any of these libraries, I just use them. What do I have to do?

- Do I have to mention the used libraries on my website or in the COPYING file in my application archive?
- Do I have to mention the authors?
- Do I have to mention all the licenses?
- Do I have to provide all the licenses somehow to my users?

Since answering to my question could be legal advice and therefore problematic, is there a project online which looks similar to mine? Perhaps there is an "anonymous" answer to my question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3):

People answering legal or licensing questions are not trying to be evasive.  But it's hard to answer licensing questions in a way that can be as accurate as the terms spelled out in the license itself.  Trying to interpret legal text can expose one to liability if one gets it even slightly wrong (even non-lawyers can be held liable).

- Many questions about GPL are answered in plain English here:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html
- The Apache License 2.0 (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) covers terms of redistribution.  See for example section 4, paragraph 4.
- The New BSD License covers terms of redistribution (for both source and binaries) in the second paragaph.  That license in particular is quite short, and easy to read.

Do not make business decisions without consulting with a legal professional.

Comment: The sad thing is, that I don't want to make business. I just want to give my stuff away for free. Copyright is broken. It needs to be redesigned from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to provide it for all those libraries that require it as per their respective licensing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the licenses, and act accordingly.